# ArcGIS Server 10.1 Integrated Windows Authentication with Token based

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, security, authentication

In ArcGIS Server 10.1 on Windows 7 and IIS, if wanting to secure services within an Intranet with Active Directory is that Integrated Windows Authentication http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000517000000 ?

If using Integrated Windows Authentication, does that dictate that web applications wanting to consume the services re-code their app if they do token based access?

I'm involved with setting up AGS 10.1 and configuring and will have numerous 3rd party web app/desktop apps wanting to consume services.  Base question is once configured are we setting the policy that any app that want gis services have to do it one way or the other?